# Sent mail ending up in trash

Tags: gmail

I set up a Gmail account. After working on an important email, I sent it last night. Several versions of the same email ended up in my trash folder. It is as if it was saved various times and ended up in the trash. This was not intentional. Two questions:

1. How do I stop this from happening?
2. Since the final version ended up in the sent folder, can I assume that it was sent?

Answer (score 1):

1. This could happen when there are connected desktop or mobile email management clients that are buggy.
2. Yes, if the message is in the Sent "folder", it was sent.

It's worth to say that Gmail doesn't have folders. It has labels, views and category tabs. This is important because if you delete a message/conversation it will be removed from all the views other than Trash. The only way to remove a message from the Sent view is deleted it (actually this assign a system label called Trash that has a related system view).

Sent view doesn't display messages that has the Trash label.

**References**
[Using labels - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en)